# Passing command line result into BUILD file

Tags: bazel

I am trying to build an external repo by defining a custom BUILD file that uses the `cmake` rule. As a part of this, I need to pass in an environment variable that contains the location of another external repo, which I can simply get via `ls $(bazel info output_base)/external/another_external_repo`. However, I'm not sure how to pass this into the BUILD file, and more specifically, specify this result in the [cmake `envs` field](https://bazelbuild.github.io/rules_foreign_cc/0.5.1/cmake.html#cmake-env). Is there a way to do this?